# How do I completely uninstall rails, ruby and rubygems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uninstallation

My system is F'd. **How do I completely uninstall rails, ruby and rubygems?**

any suggestions on where to go to reinstall from scratch? Best practices? I'd like to get back to 3.0 beta

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you to simply uninstall all Gems using `gem uninstall [name_of_gem]`, then use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to install a new Ruby version and make it the default one.

RVM also makes incredibly easy to remove a Ruby version and all its data since it installs everything in a folder within your home directory.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `gem uninstall` to delete all gems as follows:

```
gem list --no-version | xargs gem uninstall
```

If you want to keep eg. the gem `rake`:

```
gem list --no-version | grep -v "rake" | xargs gem uninstall
```

To delete only the old versions, you can run `gem clean`.

---

Also, it is possible to write all gems in a list:

```
gem list --no-version > gem_list.txt
```

and define these you want to delete:

```
cat gem_list.txt | xargs gem uninstall
```

or install:

```
cat gem_list.txt | xargs gem install
```

(eventually you have to put a `sudo` in front of a gem command. On windows use an unix console enviroment like msysGit)

Comment: Thanks! This was hot. I modified it a bit to automatically remove all bin executables and every version of a gem: 'gem list --no-version | sudo xargs gem uninstall $1 -a -x'

Answer (score 2):

Use

$gem clean

for delete all the gems.