# ruby bundle install require: no such files to load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running into troubles installing gems through bundle install from an app that i cloned through git.

Here is the what the output from bundle install looks like:

```
bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8:in `require': no such file to load --     rubygems (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11
from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `require'
from /usr/bin/bundle:4
```

I read up on google and other stackoverflow questions but the file pointed to above is in th ruby folder so it should not be anyway related to the app (which in theory would mean i wouldn't be able to bundle install for any app). any way how to fix this??

any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror

Comment: I believe this might be my issue, I ran ruby -v and it should have returned ruby 2.0.0-p0 but instead it returned ruby 1.8.7 which is very weird as I never installed it on my linux.

Comment: i think you can uninstall all. Download rails installer from http://railsinstaller.org/ and install it again

Comment: @shrikant1712 Rails installer doesn't have ruby 2.0.0 yet so I think the only way is through rvm or rbenv and I m on ubuntu so I dont think railsinstaller would work, would it? Do you happen to know the command to completely uninstall all versions of ruby in linux?

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430059/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-rails-ruby-and-rubygems

Comment: for installing rails with ruby 2.0.0 on linux/ubuntu use this command     **wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have the same question with yours, I searched a lot, but no one is the solution, at last, I asked co-worker in my company, he just ran

```
gem list
```

to list the local gems, we found there's no bundler gem, so he ran

```
gem install bundler
```

then he ran

```
bundle install
```

OK, it worked.

Comment: Getting error: Could not find modernizr-2.6.2 in any of the sources

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the directory where your gemfile is located? I believe your current directory needs to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Once `Gemfile.lock` is created,
whenever you run `bundle install`, Bundler reads this file rather than `Gemfile` to work
out the dependencies of the application and installs from it.

try check `Gemfile`/`Gemfile.lock` what is need to install

Comment: I see. Since I cloned from git I believe I would need to install most of the gems. What I did was I took out the gemfile.lock file from the project directory and put it in a different folder and ran bundle install again. But no luck, still the same error. Shouldn't it create a gemfile.lock if it doesn't see one in the project directory?

Comment: check first list gem install `gem list` and compare with your gemfile. I think the problem your gem not install but you have listed in gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're inside your `application's directory` before you `bundle install`. Because it will find the `GemFile` and check what `gem` needs to install

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command :

> sudo apt-get install rubygems build-essential

It should work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem (exact same output) and it is solved for me by simply installing the package 'rails'.